# Is there no direct translation for IS in Russian?

Tags: грамматика

I am attempting to translate the sentance *is but an image* from Fausts Chorus Mysticus. So far I have *это но копия* but I am wondering if it should be just *но копия* as the literal translation of the first sentance is *it is but an image*. How should the sentance be written? Does the meaning of *это* change depending on the context in which it is used so as to effectivey be a Russian equivalent of *is*? Thanks.

Comment: I am pretty sure Faust has been translated into Russian before (more than once, in fact). :) There are numerous ways to treat such *to be*-sentences. I would prefer using "лишь". Probably because it is a one-syllable word, so it is extremely easy to fit it into any rhythm.

Comment: "это но копия" is ungrammatical

Answer (score 7):

This is quite strange to translate English translation(!) into Russian, isn't it?

In Deutsch this excerpt sounds like:

> Alles Vergängliche
>
> Ist nur ein Gleichnis

That is "All the transient is only similitude". And in Russian: "Всё преходящее есть только подобие". In Pasternak's translation: "Всё быстротечное - символ, сравненье".

So what's the use to translate "is but an image"? If it stood completely without context I'd translate it as: "есть только образ".

Comment: +1, there's nothing to add, a very good answer.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, **но** is just the "but" as in "however". "But" as in "only" is **лишь** (and "but" as in "not X but Y" is **а**).

Depending on the exact phrase, you may not even need the **это**. Or even the dash.

The exact equivalent of *is* is **есть**, but it's mostly used to say "*there* is". It's the same for all persons and numbers in modern Russian.

Also, just in case, beware of **суть**; most Russian speakers nowadays use it incorrectly, mistaking it for some super-bookish equivalent of **есть**; in fact, it's merely its obsolete plural form ("they are"), and a sad case of a bastardised archaism.

Comment: But it is an equivalent of есть.

я есмь/ ты еси/ он есть/ вы есте/ они суть/—are't hey all equivalent?

Comment: Кстати, какой падеж лучше использовать с настоящим родом глагола  "быть"? то есть, лучше "я есмь жестоким Королем", или лучше "я есмь жестокий король"? Нужно ли использовать творительный падеж здесь?

Comment: @CoreyRoberts-Reynolds Если уж используете "есмь", то надо полностью переходить на церковнославянский - что-то вроде  "Аз есмь царь лютый".

Comment: @CoreyRoberts-Reynolds *Есмь*, etc. are well and truly gone from modern Russian, I'm afraid. If you use them, it's more or less automatically presumed that you're quoting or, at most, pretending to quote the Church Slavonic bible or an Old Russian epic or chronicle. If you do use them, nominative is better attested than instrumental (in fact, I can't think of a single example of *есмь* with instrumental).

Comment: @user4419802— думаю, что "Азъ" с твёрдым знаком было бы уместнее тут))

Comment: @ Nikolay Ershov—will people understand if I use the other forms? ты еси... итд

Comment: @CoreyRoberts-Reynolds При использовании современного алфавита для записи церковнославянских выражений ряд упрощений является нормой, в том числе пропуск буквы "ер" (а также замена "омега" на "о", "ять" на "е", отсутствие постановки ударений, неиспользование "титло" и т.д. и т.п.).

Comment: @CoreyRoberts-Reynolds "Ты еси" is understandable for Russian person much like "thou art" for English one. The meaning is quite clear although that's not what you usually say at the dinner table.

Comment: @user4419802 I think, it is understandable for a person with a degree in Russian, an educated Christian or a person who bothered to look up the old conjugation of "быть" in Wikipedia or somewhere else. I don't think an average native speaker would instantly get the meaning without any context.

Comment: @Shady_arc Even the person who never read "Отче наш иже еси на небесех" (Our Father, who art in heaven) should know some fairy tales with "Ой ты гой еси, добрый молодец" etc. Well, maybe some don't, yet some may not know what "thou art" means also.

Comment: It does not say in fairy tales what "гой еси" means (it's similar with "иже еси"—after all, "гой" and "иже" do not resemble anything meaningful). Actually, I always just understood it as speech formula—not unlike "Hello"—and learnt the meaning of "еси" directly from looking for the old conjugation.

Comment: By undestanding I really meant guessing the meaning. A native speaker might just disregard an unfamiliar word as linguistic garbage, but that's not what we typically call "understanding".

Comment: Everyone knows " я есмь Царь" because of that movie, which I'll watch some day, I guess)) I just really like collecting old useless expressions and words. For example, apparently, "ять" was maybe a verb meaning "to take" with an imperfective form of "(н)имать". Knowing this little fact helped me understand the meanings of all those similar verbs—понимать/понять, принимать/принять итд.

Comment: @"Аз есмь царь" - they said it right in that movie ;-) BTW. It was based upon this play by Bulgakov - http://www.lib.ru/BULGAKOW/ivan_vas.txt And, of course, "яти" not "ять".

Comment: @user4419802 Да, вы правы)

Comment: @Corey Roberts-Reynolds: Этот глагол, точно говоря, сначала звучал в старо-церковно-славянском  "ѩти" (jęti), а ять звали (по английской Википедии) "ѣдь" (ědĭ) или "ꙗдь" (jadĭ). Это случай, что позже эти слова стали так похожи. Надо помнить, что носовая гласная /ę/ это не было то же, что звук /a/ после /j/.

Comment: *Кстати, какой падеж лучше использовать с настоящим родом глагола "быть"? * с настоящим **временем** глагола "быть" возможен только номинатив. Творительный появляется только в прошедшем времени.

Comment: В отношении упрощений при передаче церковнославянских текстов. Нет таких общепринятых правил. У Булгакова - фонетическая передача живой речи. Так что если писать именно тексты, а не их устное воспроизведение, то надо бы "соблюдать". И еще одно. Царь говорил не на ЦСЯ а не древнерусском. Там бы это звучало "Яз есмь". Так что Булгаков - тем более не аргумент.